# Ruby - Until loop doesn't seem to be working correctly

Tags: ruby

Hey guys I'm new to Ruby so apologies if this seems like a stupid question, just can't seem to figure out what I've done wrong.

I've struggled looking online for help too not really sure what to search without writing a novel about the issue.

The purpose of the code is to keep asking the user for input, until they enter a letter, I do this by checking if the users input is in the array "alphabet" and when they do so it should check it against "word" to check if the letter is within the word that I randomly select elsewhere (i'm trying to code hangman, just for context)

here's the code:

```
def Check_Alph(word)    
    until $alphabet.include? 'guess' == true 
        puts "Please guess a letter from the alphabet"
        guess = gets.chomp
        puts "#{guess}"
    end 

    if $alphabet.include? 'guess' == true
        puts "valid letter entered, checking.."
        $guessed_Letters << guess
        if word.include? 'guess' == true
            puts "good guess! That letter was in the word!" 
            puts "Letters confirmed to be in word: #{correct_Letters}"          
        end
    end     
end
```

In the console, it just comes up "Please guess a letter from the alphabet" then when I enter a letter, it just re asks the question. I even tried outputting "guess" to check it was getting the value correctly and it was so not really sure what's going on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:

```
def Check_Alph()    
    guess == nil
    until $alphabet.include?(guess)
        puts "Please guess a letter from the alphabet"
        guess = gets.chomp
        puts "#{guess}"
    end     
end
```

Comment: The `== true` is not only superfluous. In this example (without parentheses) it actually leads an error, because `==` has a stronger binding than the method call. Ruby reads that line like this: `$alphabet.include?('guess' == true)`, what is obviously the same as `$alphabet.include?(false)`. And since `$alphabet` contains characters, this will always return `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems.

First the variable `guess` is not the same as the string `'guess'`. But you check if `$alphabet` includes the string, not the value of the variable.

Second `$alphabet.include? 'guess' == true` leads to an error, because `==` has a stronger binding than the method call. Ruby reads that line like this `$alphabet.include?('guess' == true)`. Since `'guess'` or the variable `guess` will never equal `true`, it is the same as `$alphabet.include?`(false).

As others already pointed out there is no need to check for `== true` at all, because `include?` already returns a boolean.

Change

```
until $alphabet.include? 'guess' == true
```

to

```
until $alphabet.include?(guess)
```

Furthermore you will need to define `guess` before you start the `until` block, otherwise it will be an unknown and raise an error. Just insert

```
guess = nil
```

to the top of your method.

Comment: Only problem: `guess` is set within the `until` block, so this will give a `NameError`.

Comment: I did what you said (edited it into main post so you can see) and I'm getting a new error:

"in 'Check_Alph': undefined local variable or method 'guess' for main:Object (NameError)"

Any idea what's wrong with it? Since I declared it at the start that should be fine I thought

Comment: @flanelman : Please change `guess == nil` to `guess = nil`. The `==` checks if something is equal, whereas `=` assigns a value. And you need to assign `nil` to `guess` to define the local variable `guess`.

Comment: Oh my bad, that's sorted it. Thank you so much for the help/explanation I've been struggling with this for a long time!

Answer (score 1):

you loop until $alphabet includes the string "guess".
But within the loop, you don't add anything to $alphabet, so the loop can never terminate and your if will never get to execute

Comment: Even worse. He loops until `$alphabet` includes `false`. Please see my comment above.